# Right way to create IF ELSE statement in Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to insert into a table if the value doesn't exist by using `IF EXISTS THEN`. Everytime I try to execute this query

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE addnTag
BEGIN
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE Tag.Tag = 'tt'))
THEN SELECT -1;
ELSE
INSERT INTO Tag(Tag) VALUES('tt')
SELECT last_insert_id();
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I got the

> error (1064) 'BEGIN IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE Tag.Tag =
>   'tt')) THEN SELECT -1; ELSE' at line 2 '

I can't find where is the error in my query.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Look at [IF Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) again

Comment: Try CREATE PROCEDURE addnTag ().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just missing the parentheses after the procedure name, and the semi-colon after your `INSERT` statement.

This should work:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE addnTag()
BEGIN
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE Tag.Tag = 'tt'))
THEN 
  SELECT -1;
ELSE
  INSERT INTO Tag(Tag) VALUES('tt');
  SELECT last_insert_id();
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello_

I don't get errors with this syntax:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS addnTag //
CREATE PROCEDURE addnTag()
BEGIN
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE Tag.Tag = 'tt'))
THEN SELECT -1;
ELSE
INSERT INTO Tag(Tag) VALUES('tt');
SELECT last_insert_id();
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

You were missing `()` on function declaration and the semicolon in the end of your `INSERT` statement.